# How can I prevent my Discord bot from telling the same joke twice?

Tags: python, list, discord, bots

I want to make a discordbot that can tell jokes. However I dont want it to accidently say two jokes in a row. My plan is to make two lists with jokes, one that is full of jokes that are not "used" yet and one that has jokes that are already "used". When The list with used jokes gets full it moves them over to the other list. For many of you, this is probably not a big problem, but I've just just startrd to learn phyton. Please explain what the code does so that i can understand and learn.

I haven't tried anything yet because I am still learning and dont know much phyton at all

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to create a temporary list of jokes that you will iterate through, shuffle it, and go through it in order.

```
import random
jokes = open("jokes.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
random.shuffle(jokes)

# discord func
def get_joke():
    return jokes.pop(0) #returns the first joke and removes it from the array
```

You will need some logic to refresh the list if you empty it. I.e. `if len(jokes) == 0: jokes = open("jokes.txt", "r").read().splitlines()`

Comment: Thanks allot! I will ask a friend to explain what it means. I'm just wondering if it's possible to loop the process and where should I put the list of jokes? Is it possibe to somehow separate the jokes so that the bot dont send the whole list everytime? I think thats a great idea by the way. Thanks again, this really made things clear! (:

Comment: The bot won't send the whole list, what'll happen is that it shuffles the list first, so you get a random order. Then it'll keep taking the first one from the list, and removing it. So every time you make a request you'll get a new, random joke.